# How can I create pivot table with Laravel Voyager admin?

Tags: laravel, voyager

I am using voyager to create an admin panel for my web app: When I tried to create pivote table with belongsToMany relationship.

I got this error message:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tour_category.tour_category_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select `tours`.`id` from `tours` inner join `tour_category` on `tours`.`id` = `tour_category`.`tour_id` where `tour_category`.`tour_category_id` is null). I'm newbie in using Voyager. Is there anybody that can help me to fix this error?

Comment: Hi and welcome to stack overflow :) Could you provide your database structure and or/code?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SvenHakvoort. I solved the problem )))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If someone came here to find a solution, this is how I solved it:

Let's say that you have 2 tables: **Customers** and **Companies**.

Before you try to make a belongsToMany relationship, you need to create a pivot table called **company_customer** including this fields:

*company_id* (needs to BIGINT, UNSIGNED and INDEX)
*customer_id* (needs to BIGINT, UNSIGNED and INDEX)

Then you can create a relationship between those models and select **company_customer** as pivot table